# Can't access Https on AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

ı try to open https on ec2 ubuntu v14 etc. Add security group this port and check nmap then status closed. bur remove this port from security group then this port status filtered. I don't now why ? After add https in iptables but not change anything. did you fit it anyone ?

Comment: your tomcat's ssl configuration and port defined properly? are you sure you didn't miss any part from that area?

Comment: can you give a command in your shell, and give the output? `curl https://localhost -k` on aws

Comment: $ curl https://localhost -k
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:443; Connection refused

Comment: that means, server is not configured properly

Comment: http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/42/configure-ssl-https-support-apache-tomcat-7-server try this once